# const with std::vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, constants

What is the difference between following two statements?

```
const std::vector<int> v1;
```

and

```
std::vector<int> const v2;
```

Is both statements equivalent?

Comment: Yes. They are both equal. The best way to understand `const` is to read it as applying to the token left to it (Unless it's the leftmost token - in that case it applies to the immediate token to the right).

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#overview-const

Comment: @nakiya: Please put answers in the answers section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. They are both equal. The best way to understand const is to read it as applying to the token left to it (Unless it's the leftmost token - in that case it applies to the immediate token to the right).

See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#overview-const